# Push ViewController on Push Notification Tap Won't Work When App Is Completely Closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, push-notification

I want my app to push the NewsViewController when a user taps on the received Push Notification.  In didFinishLaunching I have:

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Then, still in AppDelegate, I have:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    NewsViewController *dvController8 = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [nav pushViewController:dvController8 animated:YES];

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        UIAlertView *test = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"INACTIVE" message:@"INACTIVE" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [test show];

        [self handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:userInfo];
    }
}
-(void)handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    NewsViewController *dvController8 = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [nav pushViewController:dvController8 animated:YES];



}
```

If the user gets a push while the app is open, it goes to the NewsViewController.  If the app is running in background when they tap a push notification, it goes to NewsViewController.  However, if the user has closed the app completely from the app-switcher, and then taps on a received notification, it opens the app, without going to the NewsViewController.  How do I fix this?

Comment: if you looked at the example I provided earlier, it states you need to call it in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as well, I guess you overlooked it. This is a novice faux pas, documentation will help you. I suggest for you to start making friends with it

Comment: @soulshined you never responded earlier.  When putting that in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as well, it pushes that view controller EVERY time the app is first launched, not just when a push is received.

Comment: Then you set it up wrong. You have to do a conditional check to see if an app was opened by userInfo or just opened. You can do that by saying `if (userInfo)` does that make any sense?

Comment: that was not included in my other answer. I'm sorry for that. It should be a given though. Again. All stuff you learn ready the documentation. Which you really should start doing. And I didn't get the other notification earlier.

Comment: @soulshined That must be the issue.  The parse documentation for setting up Push notifications has nothing about any userInfo identifier.

Comment: right, but it is in Apples :) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion. This is how you determine if a terminated app is opened via notification (userInfo) or simply with icon interaction:

```
-(BOOL)application(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 ...
   NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
  // Create a pointer to extract the userInfo
  [self handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:notificationPayload];
...
}
```

And in your method you determine if it's opened via payload or not by doing a simple cross reference:

```
-(void)handleRemoteNotificationWithPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {
...
    if (payload) {
      //do something or get additional parameters from dictionary to segue alternate views
    }
...
}
```